# "Error occurred while reading WSGI handler" Problem in deploying a Django app on IIS

Tags: django, iis, deployment, django-wsgi

I am in the process of deploying a Django app in IIS. I have gone through this link 
https://www.mattwoodward.com/2016/07/23/running-a-django-application-on-windows-server-2012-with-iis/ and followed it step by step. But when I hosted my Django app named 'sample', other apps that were hosted on the IIS started showing the below error while browsing and to mention other apps were developed in different frameworks.

```
Error occurred while reading WSGI handler:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\virtualenvs\sample\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 791, in main
    env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)
  File "C:\virtualenvs\sample\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 633, in read_wsgi_handler
    handler = get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv("WSGI_HANDLER"))
  File "C:\virtualenvs\sample\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 616, in get_wsgi_handler
    raise ValueError('"%s" could not be imported%s' % (handler_name, last_tb))
ValueError: "django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()" could not be imported: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\virtualenvs\sample\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 605, in get_wsgi_handler
    handler = handler()
  File "C:\virtualenvs\sample\lib\site-packages\django\core\wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "C:\virtualenvs\sample\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "C:\virtualenvs\sample\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\virtualenvs\sample\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\virtualenvs\sample\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 107, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sample'
```

When I browse my app "sample", that too shows the same error.
I searched in stack to counter this error but could not figure out. Please help me to sort out this error.

Comment: I couldn't access the url you have provided. Could you please share the details steps about how you set the IIS to work with WSGI? Besides, if you access other app, it show the error. Could you please post details error messge?

Comment: @BrandoZhang. I have updated the working link. Please check that. And regarding the error message when I open other apps, I have already pasted the full error message in my question. Kindly help me to sort out this. Thanks